# Remove specific CSS and JS from the head

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, wp-head

I'm trying to remove some specific lines from the WP_HEAD. Now my header looks following way:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'  href='/themes/wp-e/css/bootstrap.css?ver=4.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-responsive-css'  href='/themes/wp-e/css/bootstrap-responsive.css?ver=4.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='style-css'  href='/themes/wp-e/style.css?ver=4.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='prettyPhoto-css-css'  href='/themes/wp-e/css/prettyphoto.css?ver=4.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='custom-options-css'  href='/themes/wp-e/css/options.css?ver=4.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='oswald_google-fonts-css'  href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald%3A400%2C300%2C700&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&#038;ver=4.2.2' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='thumbs_rating_styles-css'  href='/plugins/rating/css/style.css?ver=1.0.0' type='text/css' media='all' />

<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/plugins/q2w3-fixed-widget/js/q2w3-fixed-widget.min.js?ver=4.0.6'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/plugins/rating/js/general.js?ver=4.0.1'></script>
```

I need to delete all of this, but I am not good at coding and all I know is that I have to put the

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', '???' );
```

But I have no idea what to put instead of `???`.

Comment: Removing all of that would probably have adverse effect on your entire theme. Most of these can be removed by uninstalled the related plugin from the admin panel.

Comment: I am just about to use the Yepnope, so that's why I need to remove it and put directly in the header. As for the plagins, there are only two ones there.

Comment: Install the Web Developer plugin in Firefox, then use it to disable all styles. Take a look at your site. You don't want to do that.

Comment: I know what will happen. I'm about to put it directly in the header, but first I need to remove it from the wp_head

Comment: Would you be so kind to search in your theme in functions.php something like `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style` and paste in your question the entire function that contains these hooks?

Answer (score 5):

When you look at the `<style|script>` tags in your head, you will notice the `id` attribute there. Example:

```
id='bootstrap-css'
```

This – in most cases – was added by a function hooked to `wp_enqueue_scripts`, `wp_enqueue_styles` or `wp_register_scripts` or `wp_register_styles` hook. In the worst case it was hooked to either the `wp_head` or the `wp_print_scripts` hook.

In the process of backtracing those calls that add the `<script|style>` tags, you should be able to see what is attached by using something like the following from within a small plugin or your `functions.php` in a theme or child theme:

```
// See if those scripts/styles were added using the Dependency API
// Search the output for the `id` you can see rendered in the DOM
printf( 
    '<pre>%s</pre>', 
    var_export( $GLOBALS['wp_scripts']->registered, TRUE )
);
```

If you can find the script/style in above output, then you know that the asset was properly registered (and therefore is available for optimization or other handling with plugins using the WordPress API).

In case that was true, you can then search the assets up:

```
foreach( [
    'wp_enqueue_scripts',
    'wp_print_scripts',
    'wp_head',
] as $action )
    printf( 
        '<h1><code>%1$s</code></h1><pre>%1$s</pre>', 
        var_export( $GLOBALS['wp_filters'][ $action ], TRUE )
    );
```

You will get printed three "blocks" of information. Each will contain an array of callbacks that are attached to the specific hook in the array. You can then search those up using a cross file search over your themes and plugins to find the origin of your assets. Then [unregister](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=unregister+action) the actions you want to get rid of.

Comment: @IVO If that helped, please tick the check mark below the voting arrows to mark it as solution. Thanks.

Comment: that's very helpful, but I can't say it's resolved because I'm still working on the issue.

Comment: @IVO I thought I might ask if you already solved it in the past month. If you did, please add that as an answer if it differs from this one. Thanks.