# Removing specific style from wp_head

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, wp-head

I'm not a WordPress developer, I'm trying to help a friend who has a WordPress website. Here is the problem:

In the template, `wp_head()` function adds bunch of styles and scripts.

I want to remove some of them in some pages lets say this one:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='yasrcss-css'  href='https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/yet-another-stars-rating/css/yasr.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

So I searched around and based on what I've been suggested on other questions, I added this lines to `functions.php` (inside theme folder):

```
add_action( 'init', '_remove_style' );

function _remove_style() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'yasrcss-css' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'yasr.css' );
}
```

It didnt work, also I added this in `functions.php`:

```
wp_deregister_style('yasrcss-css');
```

This one didn't work either.

Am I missing something, is there anything else I should do ?

BTW, I tried this code:

```
printf( 
    '<pre>%s</pre>', 
    var_export( $GLOBALS['wp_scripts']->registered, TRUE )
);
```

as suggested [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213862/remove-specific-css-and-js-from-the-head). It didn't have that particular CSS in the output.

Comment: You're so close - the handle of the stylesheet is just `yasrcss`, not `yasrcss-css` (WordPress adds the `-css` suffix for the `id` atttribute)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Note: the file name is `functions.php`, not `function.php` (but that's probably just a typo in the question).

To remove a script or style, you must remove it after it was added. If you try to remove it before it was added, or even print `$GLOBALS['wp_scripts']->registered`, nothing will happen, since it was not added yet.

So a way to remove them is to execute the `_remove_style` function as late as possible.

Also, you need to make sure you are using the correct handle that was used to enqueue the CSS file in the first place. In this case, the correct handle is: `yasrcss` (credit to [@thedeadmedic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/1685/thedeadmedic)).

Combining all these, you may try the following CODE:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '_remove_style', PHP_INT_MAX );
function _remove_style() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'yasrcss' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove stylesheet from few selected pages, open your function.php file and put below code inside this file. In the page id array, it targets only specific page where you don't want to apply your CSS

```
add_action('init','_remove_style');
function _remove_style(){
   global $post;
   $pageID = array('20','30', '420');//Mention the page id where you do not wish to include that script

   if(in_array($post->ID, $pageID)) {
       wp_dequeue_style('your_style_sheet.css'); 
   }
}
```